# *ngFor in html angular4

Tags: angular

I am trying bind my object onto table using `*ngFor`. I would like to add array element under each of headers, `Grade` and `Names`. Is there a way to append array element by the row? So it will look like below:

[image: output]

My html:

```
<div>
  <table>
      <tr>
          <td colspan="2" style = "text-align: center;"> Names</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Grade</th>
        <th>Names</th>
      </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This may Help you

```
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Grade</th><th>Names</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr *ngFor="let data of your_data">
<td>{{ data.grade}}</td><td>{{data.name}}</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a data structure
2. Define an array of the data structure
3. interpolate it in html and create a for loop to iterate through the array and draw each row.

In **classmate.model.ts**

```
export class ClassmateType{
    name: string;
    grade: number;
}
```

In **component.ts**
(outside component body)
    import {ClassmateType} from './classmate.model.ts';

(inside component body)

```
classmates :ClassmateType[] = [
   {"billy", 6},
];
```

In **component.html**

```
<div>
  <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Grade</th>
        <th>Names</th>
      </tr>
      <tr *ngFor="let classmate of classmates">
        <td>{{classmate.grade}}</td>
        <td>{{classmate.name}}</td>
      </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```